# Does $f'(x) → 3$ as $x → 0$ imply $f'(0)$ exists? (Counterexample verification)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

If $f(x)$ is a real function such that $f'(x) → 3$ as $x → 0$, does that mean $f'(0)$ exists? I ask this because of problem 9 on page 115 of Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis. The actual question is slightly different:

> Let $f$ be a continuous real function on $ℝ^1$, of which it is known
>   that $f'(x)$ exists for all $x ≠ 0$ and that $f'(x) → 3$ as $x → 0$.
>   Does it follow that $f'(0)$ exists?

I believe it does exist because the left and right limits are equal and the function itself is continuous and defined (is there more that must be met than this?). But if continuity is not known, then I think this conclusion is invalid. Would the following counterexample be valid *if continuity is **not** assumed?*

---

Let $f(x) = 3x - 5$, for $x < 0$ and $f(x) = 3x + 5$, for $x ≥ 0$. Then clearly $f'(x) → 3$ as $x → 0$, but $f'(0)$ does not exist because of the jump discontinuity on $f(x)$ at $x=0$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462584/a-question-about-existance-of-derivative-of-function-at-zero/1462610#1462610

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your counter example when the function is not continuous is right; however, you can directly prove the existence of $f'(0)$ when assuming the continuity by L'Hoptial's theorem for limits as follows

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{f(x) - f(0)}}{{x - 0}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{f'(x)}}{1} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} f'(x) = 3$$

Comment: But doesn't that assume $f(x) - f(0)$ is zero? But this should be fine because f(x) is a continuous function. Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: @zagadka314: In fact $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \left( {f(x) - f(0)} \right) = 0$ due to continuity and $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \left( {x - 0} \right) = 0$ and hence L'Hopital is applicable. Yes, I think you got it! :)

Comment: @zagadka314: Are you there? :)

Comment: I haven't downvoted anyone. I wait a few days before I vote on anything because I like to think about it before I vote or choose a best answer. I don't know why someone downvoted you. (I just upvoted you though anyway)

Comment: And someone deleted the other answer too, I guess

Comment: @zagadka314: OK, thanks. :) I am so sorry for these anonymous down-voters! :D

Comment: I honestly don't even like downvotes, on my profile I have given only one, ever. Thank you for your help. I wish I saw the comments on the other answer, maybe the downvote worried the person and he deleted it an left.

Comment: @zagadka314: I do believe you! :) Hope you be successful with your analysis course. :)

Comment: Avoiding L'Hopital, we can say the difference quotient above equals $f'(c_x) \to f'(0).$

Comment: @zhw: The problem is to prove that the limit exist! :)

Comment: I proved it. $(f(x) - f(0))/(x-0) = f'(c_x)$ by the MVT. As $x\to 0, c_x \to 0.$ Therefore $\lim f'(c_x) = 3.$ Done.

Comment: @zhw: Sorry for that! :) I don't what MVT is! So I son't have any idea. :)

Comment: MVT = mean value theorem.

Comment: @zhw: AHA! :D, Now, I got what you said! :) Yes, that would be a good proof too! :)